# Allow ssh access on single Ethernet port

Tags: ssh, security, linux-networking, systemd, automation

I'm the guy who ask over complicated question and don't see the simple answer.

To explain quickly, I have a bunch of server (on debian 9) with 2 physical network interface, a front-end (for the app on it) and a back-end (for administration purpose).
Because i want to lock everything up, i decide to refuse ssh access to the server from the front end interface, and for "other" reason, can't just block port 22. The complicated part is that i can't just put the ip of the server back-end network in the sshd config (ListenAddress) because the ip are dynamic on purpose.

I didn't find anything on the web to just say to ssh "use that interface only" so right now i'm made a dirty fix on the systemd startup of the sshd service who look like that :

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=AdmNetIp=$(echo `ifconfig eth1 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet / {print $2}'`); sed -i "s/\(^#\)\{0,1\}ListenAddress .*/ListenAddress $AdmNetIp/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

The important part being `ExecStartPre`. it basically replace the ip in the sshd config with the actual ip of the eth1 interface before the sshd start. I really don't like that, and would like to know if there is a "cleaner" way.

I really know nothing, and usealy play with thing over my reach, so if this is just very dumb, i'm sorry for the lost of time. I'm more a tinkerer than a admin ... also French guy, so sorry for your bleeding eyes.

Thank's for reading !

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. I agree that a widely-open ssh daemon is dangerous, however, you can (and should) block unintented access using a) a firewall rules enabling only your source IPs b) a firewall rules accepting ssh for internal interface only and c) using a private, password-protected key for authentication.

Comment: i agree with you @shodanshok, really. sadly and because all ip on the admin network are dynamic, i can't apply a). and event with c) in place, and the front-end in a "local" environment, I really want to implement something like this.

Comment: But you *can* apply b) - letting the machine's firewall to accept SSH packets directed to the management interface only. You can easily do that both via firewall-cmd and plain-old iptables

Comment: @shodanshok i was thinking of it, but i can't block any port on the front end. so i can't see a way to block SSH traffic without blocking, let say port 22. is there a way to block all traffic for a process or to recognize ssh traffic without using port based filter ?

Comment: Are you *sure* you can't block anything on the front-end interface? This is in stark contrast to a basic security principle - *open what is needed only*, and block all other traffic. If you can't really block any traffic on the external interface, then I think you can not do anything different than your custom systemd pre-exec script.

Comment: @shodanshok To be honest, i'm sure i _could_. But the order form the lead are, you don't touch a thing on the external, the applicatif team "own" the interface. So because of that i have to find another way to lock thing up. In the end i'm sure they will lock up everything, but in case they don't we have to do this..

Comment: Ok, in this case I think the correct approach would to be to forward a request to the team managing the external interface, asking it to add a specific blocking rules or, on the other side, asking permission to add a rule on the interface it own. Anyway, I understand this can be problematic in some scenarios!

Comment: You want iptables which *can* specify interfaces. Say something allow port 22 on eth0 and a default deny on everything else.

Comment: @shodanshok yea, but it's not the same company, and before looking for an agreement, i'm looking for a solution on our side. dmourati as i have said, i can't block port, but thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `-oListenAddress=<ipaddress>` [when calling `sshd`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#o)?

> Can be used to give options in the format used in the configuration file. This is useful for specifying options for which there is no separate command-line flag. For full details of the options, and their values, see [sshd_config(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5)

Comment: Wow, i completely miss that argument in the man page. that clearly way cleaner than using sed to edit the config file. Thank for that ! i'm still looking if someone find a better solution, but i will do that right now.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should probably just bind to the addresses you want to listen. But in case this isn't a solution, you could try iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

I'm not 100% sure about the syntax, as I don't usually do raw iptables, but I'm sure someone will point out my errors.